$\operatorname{Spec}(R/I)\to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is closed immersion of schemes: why is the kernel locally generated by sections?
I know $Z:=\operatorname{Spec}(R/I)$ is homeomorphic to $V(I)$ which is closed in $X:=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$. Let $i:Z\rightarrow X$. Next we want show $\mathscr O_{X}\rightarrow i_*\mathscr O_Z$ is surjective. It is sufficient to check on the stalks: $R_p=\mathscr O_{X,i(z)}\rightarrow \mathscr O_{Z,z}=R_p/(IR_p)$, where $p$ denotes the prime ideal that is associated to $z$. In the end we also want to check

$\ker(\mathscr O_{X}\rightarrow i_*\mathscr O_Z)$ is locally generated by sections.

How should I do this?

I wouldn’t even check this on stalks, I would just check that it is surjective on every open set

Well, that kernel is globally generated by sections: the kernel is $\widetilde{I}$, and you can find a surjective morphism from a free module by taking a surjective morphism $R^{\oplus S}\to I$ corresponding to picking generators of $I$, then applying the associated sheaf functor.
